# converting Document objects in MongoDB 3 to POJOS

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm saving an object with a java.util.Date field into a MongoDB 3.2 instance.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
collection.insertOne(Document.parse(json));
```

the String contains:

```
"captured": 1454549266735
```

then I read it from the MongoDB instance:

```
    final Document document = collection.find(eq("key", value)).first();
    final String json = document.toJson();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    xx = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

the deserialization fails:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
>   Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Date out of START_OBJECT token

I see that the json string created by "document.toJson()" contains:

```
"captured": {
    "$numberLong": "1454550216318"
}
```

instead of what was there originally ("captured": 1454549266735)
MongoDB docs say they started using "MongoDB Extended Json". I tried both Jackson 1 and 2 to parse it - no luck.

what is the easiest way to convert those Document objects provided by MongoDB 3 to Java POJOs? maybe I can skip toJson() step altogether?

I tried mongojack - that one does not support MongoDB3.

Looked at couple other POJO mappers listed on MongoDB docs page - they all require putting their custom annotations to Java classes.

Answer (score 17):

You should define and use custom JsonWriterSettings to fine-tune JSON generation:

```
 JsonWriterSettings settings = JsonWriterSettings.builder()
         .int64Converter((value, writer) -> writer.writeNumber(value.toString()))
         .build();

 String json = new Document("a", 12).append("b", 14L).toJson(settings);
```

Will produce:

```
 { "a" : 12, "b" : 14 }
```

If you will not use custom settings then document will produce extended json:

```
 { "a" : 12, "b" : { "$numberLong" : "14" } }
```

Comment: Edit: just a simple and a plain Thank You.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks!

Comment: A potential problem with this approach is that large values of longs can lose precision. Some JSON implementations use only doubles. These have a 52 bit mantissa, which is 12 fewer bits than a long. Luckily, epochal time in milliseconds currently only needs 31 bits so we'll get away with this in many cases (for 143,000 years) but beware!

Comment: Now, it is simpler with JsonMode.RELAXED: [spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#relaxed-extended-json-example)

Comment: How you resolved this - I am getting error - Type Mismatch required Converter[Long] Actual [(Any,Any), Nothing]. Cannot resolve symbol value.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like Mongo Java driver bug, where Document.toJson profuces non-standard JSON even if JsonMode.STRICT is used. This problem is described in  the following bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2173 for which I encourage you to vote.

A workaround is to use com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(document).

Comment: com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(document) was deprecated in new versions

Answer (score 1):

I save a tag with my mongo document that specifies the original type of the object stored. I then use Gson to parse it with the name of that type.  First, to create the stored Document

```
private static Gson gson = new Gson();

public static Document ConvertToDocument(Object rd) {
    if (rd instanceof Document)
        return (Document)rd;
    String json = gson.toJson(rd);
    Document doc = Document.parse(json); 
    doc.append(TYPE_FIELD, rd.getClass().getName());
    return doc;
}
```

then to read the document back into the Java,

```
public static Object ConvertFromDocument(Document doc) throws CAAException {
    String clazzName = doc.getString(TYPE_FIELD);
    if (clazzName == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Document was not stored in the DB or got stored without becing created by itemToStoredDocument()");
    Class<?> clazz;
    try {
        clazz = (Class<?>) Class.forName(clazzName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new CAAException("Could not load class " + clazzName, e);
    }

    json = com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(doc);
    return gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
}
```

Thanks to Aleksey for pointing out JSON.serialize().

Comment: Isn't this gonna impact performance? I mean, you serialize a document to a string and then the same string is deserialized into the relevant POJO. That sounds very expensive to me...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Date object inside "myObject". In that case, you should use a `DateSerializer` that implements `JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>` and then register it with `GsonBuilder`. Sample code follows:

```
public class My_DateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>,
                                                          JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    final String dateAsString = json.getAsString();
    final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    if (dateAsString.length() == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return dtf.parseLocalDate(dateAsString);
    }
}

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                                     JsonSerializationContext context) {
    String retVal;
    final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    if (src == null)
    {
        retVal = "";
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = dtf.print(src);
    }
    return new JsonPrimitive(retVal);
}
}
```

Now register it with GsonBuilder:

```
final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
           .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new My_DateSerializer());      
final Gson gson = builder.create();
```