# Converting the org.bson.Document to Java class object

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson, bson

I am using Mongo driver for java 3.2.2 and trying to convert the bson document to valid java object. When I am using the below java code :

```
Document value = (Document)dataObject.get(VALUE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
CustomClasss classObject = gson.fromJson(value.toJson(),CustomClass.class);
```

I am getting the exception while conversion. This exception is due to date and long fields in the value document above. While converting I am getting the extra

```
$date and $numberlong
```

fields from

```
value.toJson()
```

Any suggestions how I can do this conversion.

Thanks in Advance,

Amandeep

Comment: Consider posting your document and its toJson()

Comment: Thanks mtj :  this is the tojson I am getting , you can see there is $date which violates it from conversion : 
{ "id" : 50000302,"LAST_UPDATED" : { "$date" : 1370457000000 }, "CREATED" : { "$date" : 1370457000000 } }

Comment: It looks like this was already answered at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209839/converting-document-objects-in-mongodb-3-to-pojos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209839/converting-document-objects-in-mongodb-3-to-pojos)